# How do I sign my testing suite with system key?

Tags: android, testing, system, ssh-keys

I'm writing a testing suite for my other apps that triggers system intents, specifically ACTION_DOCK_EVENT.

I know I need to add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` to my android manifest in the manifest tag and I need to install my app in /system/app instead of the normal /data/data.
I have root access so that's not a problem.

The problem I'm running into is, it appears I also need to sign my app with a system key. Where do I get a system key store, users names, and passwords? I assume I could build my own version of Android and sign it with my own keys, but since I have root access there should be an easier way right?

I have a N1 with CM7 and the emulator I'd be fine with keys for either.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=473580 is related, but maybe worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the send broadcast intents via adb with commands like:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT --ei android.intent.extra.DOCK_STATE 2
```

To test ACTION_DOCK_EVENT.
I couldn't figure out a way to do it from another app, but adb worked for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to build the OS yourself and sign it with your own keys. Root access wont help you share user id with the system.

Unless you are working with the device manufacturer, you wont be able to (legitimately) get the signing keys for the firmware.